# Filename on Windows that works with pipes in batch or PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, pipe, stdout

I have a Linux shell script with a line that looks like this:

```bash
./cmd1 -o /dev/stdout | ./cmd2
```

I'm trying to port it to Windows. I don't care whether it ends up as a batch file or a PowerShell script. I tried this in a batch file at first:

```
cmd1 -o con | cmd2
```

But this sent the output of `cmd1` to the console, and `cmd2` didn't receive any input. The problem is that `con` is the equivalent of `/dev/tty`, not `/dev/stdout`. What output filename can I pass that will be the equivalent of `/dev/stdout`, or at least close enough to make the pipe work?

Comment: does `cmd1` always output to file? Redirecting to stdout seems pointless

Comment: @phuclv Yes, it always outputs to a file. If you don't pass a filename with `-o`, it makes up its own. (If it did output to stdout in that case, then you're right, I'd just let it do that instead.)

Comment: duplicate: [Windows how to redirect file parameter to stdout? (Windows equivalent of `/dev/stdout`)](https://superuser.com/q/241272/241386)

Comment: Have you tried piping to `write-output`?

Comment: @shadow2020 Adding that to the pipeline doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Put it in your pipeline, save script. Call script from another script? Can you add more information about what you are needing to do, I feel like a lot of details are left out here. There are sooooo many ways to pipe output in powershell. What "Cmd1" are you even running because that matters also?

Comment: This is a duplicate question, please refer to ['Windows how to redirect file parameter to stdout? (Windows equivalent of `/dev/stdout`)'](https://superuser.com/questions/241272/windows-how-to-redirect-file-parameter-to-stdout-windows-equivalent-of-dev-s)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

./cmd1 -o /dev/stdout | ./cmd2 -i /dev/stdin

The equivalent command on Windows using batch or PowerShell would be:

cmd1 -o - | cmd2 -i -

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: This doesn't work either. Unlike, e.g., `con` and `nul`, the filename `-` isn't special to Windows. It is special to a lot of programs, but my `cmd1` isn't one of them, so doing that just creates a regular file named `-`.

Comment: I awarded the bounty to this answer even though it didn't work because it *could have* worked (had `cmd1` had support for it), unlike the rest of the answers, which fundamentally misunderstood the question and had no hope of working. I'm not accepting any answer yet since my problem still isn't solved yet, though.

Answer (score -2):

you can pipe it to foreach-object

```
cmd1 | % { cmd2 $_ }
```

the `$_` stands for the result of the output that is sent to the next command, sometimes with certain programs you may need to use `write-output (cmd1) | % {cmd2}` but the first one should suffice for what you want to do.

You can also store the output of the first command like this

`$var = cmd1`

or like this

`cmd1 > $var`

Comment: This doesn't help, since `cmd1` doesn't output anything for the pipe to pick up.